# 451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate

Tags: sendgrid

I am following this [link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html) for a test. But I receive

> 451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate

at step 4:

> 4.Enter your Base64 converted API key in the next line as the password.

Does it mean I entered a wrong Base64 converted API key? But I have double checked the key. What's going on?

By the way, I am also using Postfix, and in `/var/log/maillog` it says

> certificate verification failed for [smtp.sendgrid.net](http://smtp.sendgrid.net/)[198.37.144.225]:587: untrusted issuer /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority

Then I followed this [link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/errors_and_troubleshooting.html) to add the certificate, but I still cannot send the email by Postfix, perhaps the reason is `451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate`?

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of '451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate'
- because IP not whitelisted

You need to whitelist your NAT or the Public IP of the instance in the Sengrid site then the steps described here would work -

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. Run the TELNET test again (following the instructions [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html)),
 but instead of using the API username `apikey` and your API key, use your base64 converted login username and password for Step 3 and step 4.

This should return a `235 Authentication successful` response. This will mean you've successfully connected.

Given that the username/password test is successful, consider opening your API key Permissions to Full Access and try sending and email. If that works, you can use [this link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/api_key_permissions.html) to adjust your permissions for your application.